# How to make a Stream from a For Loop

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a for loop that gets values passed through argument and if certain condition is meet, it creates a new block object. I need to transform this loop to Stream. I search another cases like this, but as the condition of this loop is not a value of the iterator i, but a date condition, I couldn't figure it out how to limit the stream. Also, the items are not premade, like in other examples, but they're being made in the progress. Here is the code:

```
class DateBlock {    
    final Instant from;
    final Instant to;

    DateBlock(Instant from, Instant to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public static List<DateBlock> blockize(ZonedDateTime fromDate, 
            ZonedDateTime toDate, 
            int blockSize, 
            ChronoUnit blockSizeUnit) {
        List<DateBlock> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean reachedDate = false;
        for (int i = 0; !reachedDate; i++) {
            ZonedDateTime minDate = fromDate.plus(i * blockSize, blockSizeUnit);
            ZonedDateTime maxDate = fromDate.plus((i + 1) * blockSize, blockSizeUnit);
            reachedDate = toDate.isBefore(maxDate);
            blocks.add(new DateBlock(minDate.toInstant(), maxDate.toInstant()));
        }

        return blocks;
    }
}
```

How I need to proceed?

Comment: That does not look like a loop you would convert to a stream (nor one that could be converted). And even if you were successful, I am very sure, that in the end you would call `forEach(action)` on that streama nd include the exact same code in it

Comment: There is no significant advantage to returning a `Stream` from a result that is a `Collection` instance.  If clients of your API want to iterate over the collection, then `Collection` already extends `Iterable`.  If clients want to process a sequence of elements instead, then `Collection` has a `stream()` method already in its API.

Comment: I agree with @XtremeBaumer, you don't have any Collection to iterate over.

Comment: You can't make the collection on the go as in the for loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is `Stream.iterate` to iterate over an infinite stream which we can use to create elements from `start` that will be incremented by `blockSize` using some `ChronoUnit`.

First,keep generating `(i + 1)` days in `.map(...)`, and check if they are `beforeEnd`,then if so, add to list `blocks.add` creating `new DateBlock(i-1, i)`. Also use `allMatch()` short-circuiting terminal operation to stop processing.

Disadvantage here is that you need to check `beforeEnd` 2 times. In java 9 there is `.takeWhile` operation, thought.

```
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(5);
Predicate<ZonedDateTime> beforeEnd = date -> date.isBefore(end);
final long blockSize = 1;

List<DateBlock> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
Stream.iterate(start, d -> d.plus(blockSize, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
        .map(d -> d.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
        .peek(i -> {
            if(beforeEnd.test(i))
                blocks.add(new DateBlock(i.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS), i));
        })
        .allMatch(beforeEnd);
```

Running that I get dates like

`[DateBlock{from=2019-04-11...,to=2019-04-12...,
 ..., 
 DateBlock{from=2019-04-15...,to=2019-04-16...}]`

UPDATE
I understand people say this implementation may not look nice at first thought, it's only because java8 has not proper method for it, just take a look how elegant it may look with `.takeWhile` method.

```
Predicate<DateBlock> beforeEnd = dateBlock -> dateBlock.to.isBefore(end);
Stream.iterate(start, d -> d.plus(blockSize, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
        .map(i -> new DateBlock(i, i.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)))
        .takeWhile(beforeEnd)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```